# Polar coordinates parameters

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

> Sketch in the same diagram the curves with polar equations $r=2a\cos\theta$ and $2r(1+\cos\theta)=3a$ and find the polar coordinates of their points of intersection. What is the polar equation of the common chord of the two curves?

I don't understand what is meant by common chord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chord joins two points on a curve. Here common chord refers to the line joining the two points of intersection.